# Pandas Dataframe check intersection and fill in a new dataframe

Tags: python, csv, pandas, dataframe

I have two lists of protein sequences, I have to check every entry's existence in the two lists, say like

```
list A = [1,2,3,4]
list B= [3,4,5]

## just an example. The result would be convert into csv
result = [
[1, true, false],
[2, true, false],   ## 2 only exist in the first list
[3, true, true],    ## 3 exist in both lists
[4, true, true],
[5, false, true]
]
```

I load the two sequences into two different dataframes but I can't figure out how to manipulate them within the dataframe. I ended up load them into a set and form a list then convert back into dataframe. I think the right way should be do it natively within the dataframes

```
def FindDifferences():    
    df1 = pd.read_csv('Gmax_v6_annotation_info.txt', names=['name'], usecols=[0], delimiter='\t')
    df2 = pd.read_csv('Gmax_v9_annotation_info.txt', names=['name'], usecols=[2], delimiter='\t')
    v6_set = set(df1['name'])
    v9_set = set(df2['name'])
    result = []
    for val in v6_set:
        if val in v9_set:
            result.append([val, True, True])
        else:
            result.append([val, True, False])
    for val in v9_set:
        if val not in v6_set:
            result.append([val, False, True])
    result_df = pd.DataFrame(result, columns=['name', 'inv6', 'inv9'])
    result_df.to_csv('result_csv.csv', index=False, header=False)
    return
```

I did attempt to do

`new_dataframe.loc[new_dataframe.shape[0]] = [val, False, False]` instead of appending to a native list

But it was so slow that I have to cut the execution. With the list implementation it takes not even a second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `merge` with `indicator` turned on which creates a *_merge* column that gives information about whether the value in the join column exists in the left or right or both data frames, and then you can create two indication columns from it:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'name': A})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'name': B})

(df1.merge(df2, how='outer', indicator=True)
 .assign(inv6 = lambda x: x._merge != "right_only", 
         inv9 = lambda x: x._merge != "left_only")
 .drop("_merge", 1))
```

[image]

Comment: You are a genius ! Exactly what I'm looking for!

Comment: Oh wow I did a timeit analysis on both solutions. Amazingly, they have almost no performance difference.
`In [7]: %timeit FindDifferences()
1 loop, best of 3: 386 ms per loop

In [16]: %timeit pandas_solution()
1 loop, best of 3: 389 ms per loop`

Comment: https://github.com/shaoqin2/AlgorithmSpeedTests/tree/master/check_existance_in_two_lists

Comment: Thanks for sharing the result. It's very interesting to see the performance like that.