# Pandas dataframe merge doesn't perform better than appending to a new list

Tags: python, algorithm, performance, pandas, join

Basically I have two lists and I have to check each value's existance in both lists

```
list A = [1,2,3,4]
list B= [3,4,5]

## just an example. The result would be convert into csv
result = [
[1, true, false],
[2, true, false],   ## 2 only exist in the first list
[3, true, true],    ## 3 exist in both lists
[4, true, true],
[5, false, true]
]
```

I was using list and set to appending each row into a list. As [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42847053/pandas-dataframe-check-intersection-and-fill-in-a-new-dataframe) suggests, I used Dataframe merge to test the performance.

Amazingly, the dataframe `merge` with `indication` method doesn't outperform the very stupid list solution.

The two solutions are here

Stupid one: should be a O(n) solution since check in set is O(1)

```
def FindDifferences():    
    df1 = pd.read_csv('Gmax_v6_annotation_info.txt', names=['name'], usecols=[0], delimiter='\t')
    df2 = pd.read_csv('Gmax_v9_annotation_info.txt', names=['name'], usecols=[2], delimiter='\t')
    v6_set = set(df1['name'])
    v9_set = set(df2['name'])
    result = []
    for val in v6_set:
        if val in v9_set:
            result.append([val, True, True])
        else:
            result.append([val, True, False])
    for val in v9_set:
        if val not in v6_set:
            result.append([val, False, True])
    result_df = pd.DataFrame(result, columns=['name', 'inv6', 'inv9'])
    result_df.to_csv('result_csv.csv', index=False, header=False)
    return
```

Dataframe one, credit to Psidom

```
In [13]: def pandas_solution():
    ...:     df1 = pd.read_csv('Gmax_v6_annotation_info.txt', names=['name'], usecols=[0], delimiter='\t')
    ...:     df2 = pd.read_csv('Gmax_v9_annotation_info.txt', names=['name'], usecols=[2], delimiter='\t')
    ...:     df1.merge(df2, how='outer', indicator=True)
                .assign(inv6 = lambda x:x._merge != "right_only", inv9 = lambda x:x._merge != "left_only")
                .drop("_merge", 1).to_csv('resultcsv.csv')
```

Result

```
In [7]: %timeit FindDifferences()
1 loop, best of 3: 386 ms per loop

In [16]: %timeit pandas_solution()
1 loop, best of 3: 389 ms per loop
```

https://github.com/shaoqin2/AlgorithmSpeedTests/tree/master/check_existance_in_two_lists

#### Question

I would like to know what happened under the hood and what's the takeaway from this behavior. the merge solution intuitively seems so much better.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @DYZ quote from the middle part of the question "I would like to know what happened under the hood and what's the takeaway from this behavior." I probably should bold it or move it down

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`df1.merge(df2, how='outer', indicator=True)` itself is optimized to be quite fast. So that part of your operation should indeed be better than your `O(n)` list operation.

However, in addition to calling `merge` you also call `DataFrame.assign`. This function takes an arbitrary function as an input, and generates (and sets) an arbitrary `dict` of outputs on your object.

Since `pandas` doesn't *know* anything about the function that you're going to use, it can't apply any clever speed-ups to it get it to work faster. All it can do is iterate over your `DataFrame` and run your operation one input at a time. This is of course no better than just iterating over a list!

The implementation is a bit difficult to show because `pandas` does something very clever with its API here. `DataFrame.apply` behaves similarly, however, so here's a demo of what this means in practice:

```
%timeit pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100, 100)).sum()
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.2 ms per loop
%timeit pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(100, 100)).apply(lambda row: sum(row), axis=1)
100 loops, best of 3: 7.63 ms per loop
```